# MATLAB how to store Value in Variable without scientific/exponential notation?

Tags: matlab, decimal, notation, exponential

I've got a Matrix, let's say x, that contains seven values in exponential notation. Next i want to write this Variable to a textfuile, but without the exponential but with a decimal notation.

I tried `str2num(num2str(exportdata, '%15.4f'));` and `fprintf` but this only works for displayed data but not for storage as far as I know.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please show some of your code, and see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use fprinf to print directly to the file. For example:

```
v = [173524132746354.21542, 987678898521232.32547]

fid = fopen('file.txt','w')
fprintf(fid, '%0.2f, %0.2f', v)
fclose(fid)
```